# How to call api from external component

Tags: content-hub, content-hub-scripting

I am developing external component in Sitecore Content Hub 4.X. I want to call REST API as a current logged user.
Custom component expose some options, for example `options.api` but it is only text...

https://docs.stylelabs.com/content/4.0.x/integrations/integration-components/external-page-component/external-page-options.html?redirect=true

but how to call for example `options.api.entities` using credentials of already logged user?

Answer (score 6):

The call will be authenticated based on the Content Hub cookies you have. So it will use the logged in user to make the call.

You can use jQuery to make the call, the library is already loaded.

```
$.ajax({
   url: `${options.api.entities.href}&skip=0&take=10`,
   contentType: 'application/json',
   type: 'get',
   success: (data) => {
      callback(data);
   }
});
```

Comment: this works for get, but doesn't for post :/ I am api user and I assigned myself to all groups and still 403 is returned.

Comment: you will need X-Auth-Token in header for POST

Comment: I just faced the same problem, only GET works in this way, in order to make POST, PUT, DELETE requests either X-Auth-Token or oAuth token have to be used. That means username and password (in case OAuth used - also client id and secret) have to be hardcoded somewhere in external user component. This makes such writable requests challenging, and the scenario if one would like to run them in context of the currently logged in users - impossible

Answer (score 2):

After some help from colleagues, I was able to get the way to perform PUT and POST requests without any additional authentication (it shares then current cookies).
There are jQuery extension methods `$.rest.put(url, objecttoput)` and `$.rest.post(url, objecttopost)` that can do that:

You can look for examples into browser dev tools.
For example:

[image]

UPD: there is also method `$.rest.del(url)` to do a DELETE request

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, we use content hub scripts and provide them current user name.

On ExternalComponent we call the Script with pre-defined authToken for script user:

```
const userName = options.user.name;
fetch(scriptUrl, {
  method:'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'x-auth-token': options.config.authToken
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    userName,
  })
})
```

On the Script side [impersonate](https://docs.stylelabs.com/contenthub/4.1.x/content/integrations/script-common-documentation/impersonation.html) MClient with that user:

```
var data = Context.Data as JObject;
var userName = data["userName"].Value<long>();
var authenticatedClient = await MClient.ImpersonateAsync(userName);
```

Then you can call the APIs as usual.